# Mysql global privileges all tables except one

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

Is it possibile to set ALL PRIVILEGES to an user and than deny it only for specific one?
I need to grant a user to create and populate new databases, however he must not change one specific private database. For new database creation I need to add global priviles, how ever this grant also alter on the private database.

Is it possibile?

Comment: My guess is grant all and then revoke on that one table ?

Comment: Seems that Mysql has a top-down privileges so the global grant wins against revoke on single table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288554/mysql-grant-all-privileges-to-database-except-one-table