# Disable manually setting auto-incremented ids in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to disallow users from inserting into a table `product` (which has auto-incremented ids) if they're setting the id manually.

So this would be valid (id generated automatically since it's set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`):

```sql
INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES ("Product1")
```

But this wouldn't (id being set manually):

```sql
INSERT INTO product (id, name) VALUES (10, "Product1")
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Are the users working with the database directly? No backend/CURL program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger logic may help.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode := '';

CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val INT
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 123;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER fail_explicit_id
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.id <> 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Explicit ''id'' value is not allowed.';
  END IF;
END
```

```
INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (111);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 222);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 333);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT, 444);
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (456, 555);
```

> ```
> Explicit 'id' value is not allowed.
> ```

```
SET SESSION sql_mode := CONCAT_WS(',', @@sql_mode, 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO');
SELECT @@sql_mode;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 666);
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 777);
```

> ```
> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'test.PRIMARY'
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 666 |
| 123 | 111 |
| 124 | 222 |
| 125 | 333 |
| 126 | 444 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nR-ntIVR)

Answer (score 2):

Give the user column-level permissions.

```
grant insert(`name`) on yourdatabase.product to theuser@thehost;
```

Then the user tries these:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES ("Product1");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO product (id, name) VALUES (10, "Product1");
ERROR 1143 (42000): INSERT command denied to user 'theuser'@'thehost' for column 'id' in table 'product'
```

Comment: That's pretty good, thank you! I didn't know there were column-level permissions. I accepted Akina's answer because it seemed a bit cleaner, hope you understand!

Comment: Yes, of course. Be careful with triggers, though... they have been known to cause serious performance issues.

Comment: For anyone wondering, it's not currently possible to grant table- or database-wide insert permission and then make an exception for specific columns. See [How to "subtract" privileges in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8131849/1662230) and [ALL PRIVILEGES except one table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24204504/1662230) for more details.