# How to revoke all privileges for a user in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ddl, privileges, sql-revoke

How do I revoke all privileges for a user in SQLPlus?
I'm logged in as `sysdba` and I would like to revoke all privileges for a regular user.

I googled this query

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM user [, user] ...
```

but I don't understand what should I put for user, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL grant all privileges to database except one table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288554/mysql-grant-all-privileges-to-database-except-one-table)

Comment: whether you want to `revoke` `system privilege` or `Object privilege` ?

Answer (score 4):

Here answer depends on whether you want to revoke **system privileges** or **object privileges**.
There is syntax change for the both.

But as you are logging through sysdba i am guessing that you want to revoke `system privileges`.

```
revoke sysdba from user_name;
```

Here replace *user_name* with your actual user. like

```
revoke sysdba from nagendra;
```

**Updated :**
And to revoke all `system privileges` we can use :

`revoke all privileges from user_name`

`object privilege` means previleges on `tables` `procedures` `functions` and to revoke this use :

```
revoke all on object_name from public
```

Example

```
revoke all on nagendra_table from public
```

This will remove all existing privilegs on table `nagendra_table` from `all users`

Answer (score 2):

*`user`* is the name of the use you want to revoke the privileges from. The `grant option` clause is MySQL syntax, and does not exist in Oracle Enterprise Databases. So, if I'd like to revoke all of `r_mat`'s privileges, I'd use:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM r_mat;
```

Comment: Its not working, when I try your solution, I get this msg --> ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, as the question was tagged. It won't apply to oracle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake I meant sqlplus not mysql

Comment: @R_Mat oh, so it is Oracle then. I amended the syntax in my answer to fit this new information - see there.